# How to make subsequent, authenticated calls to Google API using Passport.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, passport.js

I'm trying to authenticate and authorize users with Passport.js using Google API. I have G Suite and all my users are part of a G Suite organization. I've set up a bunch of roles in G Suite to use with my custom app.

The authentication part is fine and works as intended. The problem is that I need to make a subsequent call to `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/customer/roleassignments` with the `userKey` of the logged-in user to get all the assigments that this user has and I'm not sure what's the best way to do that.

This is what the relevant parts of my `/login` route look like now:

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.BASE_URL + '/login/google/callback'
  },
  function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    return done(null, profile)
  })
)

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // Render the login button
})

router.get('/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: [
      'email',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement.readonly'
    ]
  })
)

router.get('/google/callback', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('google', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login?error=no_user') }

    req.login(user, function (err) {
      if (err) { return next(err) }

      const accessToken = req.user.accessToken
      // Maybe do something here?

      return res.redirect('/')
    })
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

I can store the `accessToken` to the user session when I get it and just make a callback using the token as a bearer token and this probably works fine, but is this really the way it's supposed to work? Does Passport.js provide some kind of mechanism to make the subsequent, authenticated calls easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigations, I believe you're supposed to modify the Strategy callback if you have additional steps to take after the initial authentication.

So to get custom User Roles set up in G Suite Admin, you could do it like this using the external `request` library:

```
import request from 'request'

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.BASE_URL + '/login/google/callback'
  },
  function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/' +
      process.env.GOOGLE_CUSTOMER_ID +
      '/roleassignments' +
      '?userKey=' +
      profile.id

    request.get(url, {
      auth: {
        bearer: accessToken
      }
    }, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Could not authenticate.' })
      }
      const items = JSON.parse(response.body).items
      let role = null
      const roles = items.map((value) => {
        return value.roleId
      })

      if (roles.includes(process.env.GOOGLE_ROLE_ID_ADMIN)) {
        role = 'ADMIN'
      } else if (roles.includes(process.env.GOOGLE_ROLE_ID_OTHER)) {
        role = 'OTHER'
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'No valid user role' })
      }

      console.log('User role is ' + role)
      profile.role = role
      return done(null, profile)
    })
  })
)
```

If you assign the acquired role to the `profile`, you can easily access it later with `req.user.role`.